# Enumerable.Repeat perform badly with for loop on initializing List<>

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I am writing a list of `PropertyInfo` for store class's properties automatically. But it perform weirdly. This is what I wrote:

Class for properties:

```
public class ValueLib
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public bool Value3 { get; set; }
}

public class InfoLib
{
    public System.Reflection.PropertyInfo Info { get; set; }  // Store PropertyInfo of properties in ValueLib.
}
```

I'm expecting create a list `List<InfoLib>` to store the information. Which should have this result when I print `InfoLib.Info`:

```
Int32 Value1
String Value2
Boolean Value3
```

Here is the main script:

```
public class Program
{
    public ValueLib ValueLib { get; set; }
        
    private static List<InfoLib> _infoLib;
    public static List<InfoLib> InfoLib
    {
        get
        {
            _infoLib = _infoLib ?? new List<InfoLib>(Enumerable.Repeat(new InfoLib(), typeof(ValueLib).GetProperties().Length).ToList());  // Initialize list using Enumerable. ------(1)
            _infoLib.ForEach(p => p.Info = typeof(ValueLib).GetProperties()[_infoLib.IndexOf(p)]);  // Check every properties and stored the corresponding PropertyInfo.
            return _infoLib;
        }
        set { _infoLib = value; }
    }
        
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InfoLib.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.Info));  // Print every propertyInfo.
    }
}
```

When compile this program, it come up with this, which I didn't expect:

```
Int32 Value1
Int32 Value1
Int32 Value1
```

After a several attempt, I found it work when replacing `(1)` with this script:

```
if(_infoLib != new List<InfoLib>(Enumerable.Repeat(new InfoLib(), typeof(ValueLib).GetProperties().Length)))
{
    _infoLib = new List<InfoLib>();
    // Use normal for loop to initialize the list
    for(int i = 0; i < typeof(ValueLib).GetProperties().Length; i++)
    {
        _infoLib.Add(new InfoLib());
    }
}
```

It seems work but I wonder what's wrong with my original script. Thank you for any replies.

Comment: `_infoLib = typeof(ValueLib).GetProperties().Select(p => new InfoLib() { Info = p }).ToList()`.

Comment: problem solved, thanks!